# Viewing boot in serial Console on GCP Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine, boot

I am diagnosing a boot process of a custom image on GCP Compute Engine. I am trying to figure out how I can view the boot from the serial console or anywhere else. This is all I see on the serial screen:

```
serialport: Connected to *********.asia-southeast2-a.instance-2-serial-tty2 port 1 (session ID: 4661c0157f5758d46a97b560d1b0671cc02ad8b4, active connections: 2).
Total RAM Size = 0x0000000100000000 = 4096 MiB
CPUs found: 2     Max CPUs supported: 2
SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-google)
Machine UUID 3b9f104e-7f4f-14c6-c226-134be788ae90
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=33554432 = 16384 MiB
drive 0x000f22e0: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=33554432
Sending Seabios boot VM event.
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
```

I can boot successfully in VirtualBox, so I can make any changes to the image if required and have tried using other serial ports:

`sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS1.service`

The screenshots for the VM also come up blank black screen.

How do I go about diagnosing the boot for this in GCP? Please advise incase this is the wrong forum for this post.

Comment: The last line `Booting from Hard Disk 0...` means that the boot loader is loaded into memory and execution is transferred to that code. The code does not execute properly and the VM hangs. There is something wrong with the boot loader code or where it is stored on disk (disk translation related issues). The logical disk translation `LCHS=1024/255/63` is probably correct. What is the disk format (MBR/UEFI)? Probably not related but did you install the Guest tools before creating and uploading the disk image? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment

Answer (score 1):

As per [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#test_image) if you see the `Booting from Hard Disk 0...` at the serial console then you must [troubleshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/vm-startup#persistent_book_disks) the issues  from compute engine environment. Most importantly you need to check the file system for your problematic vm's. To do this please follow the steps:

Step1- Detach the disk from the instance

```
gcloud compute instances delete old-instance --keep-disks boot
```

Step2- Create a new instance with latest Google provided image

```
gcloud compute instances create debug-instance
```

Step3- Attach the disk to the new-vm as a secondary disk and don't mount the disk at all

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk debug-instance 

  --disk DISK 

  --device-name debug-disk
```

Step4- Connect to new instance

```
gcloud compute ssh debug-instance
```

Step5- look for the secondary disk, it might be sdb1

```
lsblk
```

step6- Check the file system using the command

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
```

Step7: Mount the file system

```
sudo mkdir /mydisk
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mydisk
```

Step8: check that disk has kernel files:

```
ls /mydisk/boot/vmlinuz-*
```

At the end please check the MBR is valid using the command:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb print
```

If MBR valid it will show information about file system:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.7GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags:
 Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
  1      2097kB  10.7GB  10.7GB  primary  ext4         boot
```

Now detach the secondary disk  from the new instance and attach it to old VM as a boot disk or create a image from the disk to create new instance from the image.